# Finding height for a point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, topography

How can I find the height in for a given topographic  point in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin that made for this purpose [image]
The plugin will appear in the Plugins toll bar [image]

Once you click it you will have a marker and when you click on a point you will it will find you the height above sea level[image]
If you will do it for several points it will make you an attribute table [image]